# How to reference header files in visual studio 2017 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, header-files

I have downloaded and tried to build The oxygine engine project with VS 2017 Community. The stringutils.cpp file from it gives me the following when I try to compile:

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL_stdinc.h': No such file or directory
```

hovering the `#include` statement it says `cannot open source file 'SDL_stdinc.h'`

I checked

> Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories

and it references the path the header files are in. I have even added another path representing the absolute path. I tried a different folder, a different download of the header files, all to no avail.

What do I need to do to get this right?

Is there any reason for a header to not work? (version mismatch or something)
Is a header not working if the corresponding dll or lib is missing?
If so, how do I know it is found by VS?

Comment: So how do `Additional Include Directories` and `VC++ Directorirs->Include Directories` look like in your case? This is clearly incorrect directory path issue.

Comment: This path was already added
`..\..\..\..\SDL\include\ `

This is the same location as an absolute path
`C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Oxygen\oxygine\SDL\include`

It doesn't matter if both exist, it still is not found even though the header is in that folder

Comment: Did you add a `;` at the path end?

Comment: For the include directory, it looks like this:

`$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath); `

Comment: No I didn't, neither path ends with a semicolon (there's quite a few)

Comment: @VTT do you mind giving me one more advice? I have no idea how to verify the folders are inspected properly or how to tackle this problem in any other way than clothing those headers around and see if it works, which wouldn't tell me why it didn't actually

Comment: I've managed to build it on VS2015 without adjusting generated projects. `D:\Projects\oxygine\oxygine-framework\..\SDL\include` is already listed in Additional include directories. Maybe your CMake is not up to date or you've changed something in these projects?

Comment: Oh hey, thanks for the reply. I'll have a look tomorrow then, maybe something is different in VS 2017 that it's this difficult to get working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the path for oxygine in the oxigine project properties was setup like this `..\..\..\..\SDL\include\` but had to be setup like that `..\..\SDL\include\`